# Send an ID via the URL for Angular views

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I am using Angular to create my single page views but I am struggling to pass an ID from an sql select via the URL.

I have created my view like so:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when("/jobSingle", {
            templateUrl : "jobSingle.php"
        });    
    });
```

Works great shows me the correct page. I am TESTING data so this is open to SQL injection but I am playing around with Angular so don't freak out - I am linking to the single view page from another view like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM jobs";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { // Start while
        echo $row['title'];
        echo '<a href="#jobSingle?id=' . $row['id'] . '">View Job</a>';
        ?>

        <div class="lightboxHide animated fadeInUp">
            <div id="mylightbox">
                <?php echo $row['title']; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
    } // End while
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

So where I have `echo '<a href="#jobSingle?id=' . $row['id'] . '">View Job</a>';` it appears to be the correct url and it opens the correct view but when I GET the id form the URL and var dump it i get nothing...

```
$jobId = $_GET['id'];
var_dump($_GET);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE id = '$jobId'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { // Start while
        echo $row['title'];
    } // End while
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

My var dump just simply shows....

```
array(0) { } 0 results
```

Aswell when I do a var_dump on the `$_GET` I get a `NULL` value returned... Its almost like the url is being ignore, well the Id is at least...

Is this even possible OR am I missing the point here? I am learning angular as I work with Php primarily I wanted to know if this was do able?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Href `#jobSingle?id=...` in your `<a></a>` tag sets `<fragment>` part of a URL. When you open a website your browser does not include `<fragment>` part of a URL in its request.

To see the difference just swap `<query>` and `<fragment>` parts in your ULR to fulfill correct URL scheme. For example: `?id=1#jobSingle`.

Here is the common URL syntax to clarify what I'm talkign about:

```
<scheme>://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<path>?<query>#<fragment>
```

Everything that goes after # mark in URL is treated like a fragment.

RFC 1738 and RFC 3986 contain full explanation for raised topic.

Comment: Ok so I understand and followd your advice so my URL now looks like `http://localhost/Angular/?job_id=3#/jobSingle` but still returning `NULL`

Comment: So you put this link in your browser, refresh your page and `var_dump($_GET)` shows you NULL? Are you sure?

Comment: Do you open this path directly or through a serverside router script?